# Alias for Drupal "Sites" folder with Apache on Windows Server 2008

Tags: drupal, zend

I'm having to move a number of sites from a LAMP stack to a WAMP one, provided by Zend, and I've hit a problem.  Our architecture is a number of loadbalanced web servers which have their own local webapp drives which are kept in sync with one server performing as the master copy.  There is then a separate DFS share provided to all web servers from our pillar san.  Usually a Drupal install under our LAMP cluster would have the main Drupal web app in a local HTDOCS mount for each server and the SITES directory within Drupal would then be symlinked out to the DFS or NFS share so that there is a common FILES and TMP directory.

The problem I'm having is that there seems to be no equivalent of symlinks on Win Server 2008, shortcuts have a .ink at the end making Apache see them as a distinct file.  So I've tried using an alias call in the vhost file like this;

```
<Location /drupal-626/sites>
    Order deny, allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Alias /drupal-626/sites "Z:\Path to alternate sites directory"

The root for this test is;

```
http://main-domain-url/drupal-626/
```

Unfortunately this isn't working so I'm wondering if any of you have a solution which would work?

Many thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I can use

```
MKLINK
```

which replicates symlinks on windows server.